# Blog with horizontal columns

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering how does one get horizontal columns like this: [image]

without the articles being cut off and continuing in the next column? I want them to be different heights. Like Post A is 60% height, then Post B is 40% height, then next column Post C is 30% height and Post D is 70% height.

I tried this, but it doesn't work that good when scrolling.

```
#featured-posts-container {
    -webkit-column-count:  4;
    -webkit-column-gap:  10px;
    -webkit-column-fill:  auto;
    -moz-column-count:  4;
    -moz-column-gap:  10px;
    -moz-column-fill:  auto;
    column-count:  4;
    column-gap:  15px;
    column-fill:  auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is a column. I think that is a `background-color`.

Then the developer made the text elements display inline to each other. Thus the margins between the paragraphs is now a column for you. Where in real it isn't.